# How to query firestore when document does not exist

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to keep a record of user tokens when they subscribe to a topic once.

Im trying to make a query where if a document does not exist with the current user_token, it would create a new document for them, attaching their user_token.

If a document already exist with the same user_token , then it should not run this query and replicate is self, which is my main problem.
[both document have the same token_id and are duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceiAZ.png)

This is what I tried

```
//Variables
  let db = Firestore.firestore()
  let user_token = "dpc3GPfPzUArj...IdEac5hWYWI8"

//If no document exist with user_token create a new one
db.collection("tokenList").whereField("token_id",isNotEqualTo: user_token).getDocuments() { 
    (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err { print("Error getting documents: \(err)") } 
    else {
    db.collection("tokenList").document().setData(["token_id" : user_token])                                                                      
    }
 
//If one already exist, this query should not run
```

Comment: What is the need to query for the document if the purpose is to create one if it doesn't exist and do nothing if it doesn't? Just create the document whether it exists or it doesn't. I assume there is other logic in play here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I figured out, I forgot to add a small line when following the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert the logic: Search for the first document `where token_id === user_token` (you can limit it to 1 result). If there's a result, it exists. If there's not, it doesn't exist.

You could also have the token_id be the actual ID of the document, which makes sense if it's the primary identifier.

Comment: I forgot to add a small line of code after the else statement from the documentation,  `for document in querySnapshot!.documents {} `, thank you for the recommendation.